# How to set the page number in Chinese characters rather than Arabic numberals?

Tags: page-numbering, chinese

By the default setting, I get page numbers in Arabic numerals like 1,2,3,etc. How can I get a series of page numbers in Chinese characters like 一, 二, 三, (simplified Chinese) or 壹, 贰, 叁 (traditional Chinese)?

Comment: Please give a minimal working example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **simplified** case, you can try the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{ctex}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\chinese{page}}
```

It will produce page numbers such as `一、二、三、...`。By the way if you use `ctexart`(`ctexbook`) instead of `article`(`book` repsectively) for the documentclass, `ctex` package will be not necessary.

For the **traditional** case, it's a little complicated that `zhnumber` and `fancyhdr` should be use at the same time.

```
\usepackage{zhnumber,fancyhdr}
\zhnumsetup{style={Traditional,Financial}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{你想要的页眉}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{页眉其它内容}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\zhnumber{\thepage}}
```

You can revised the codes above to get what you want.

Comment: You can also use the `zhnumber` package for this if you do not wish to use `ctex`, for example, if mixing ideographic scripts with `babel`.

Comment: @Davislor For Chinese documents, now `ctexart`, `ctexbook`, `ctexbeamer` and so on are better choices than others.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kuttens

Comment: @KuttensThe page numbers are 一、二、三… now. But how about the traditional Chinese characters like 壹、贰、叁.…？ I know the users on stackexchange mostly write in English and they may  not be familiar with  the usage of Chinese character in Tex. Since the largest Chinese Tex forum has been shut down, I have to ask my questions here.

Comment: @Humblerose You write the document in traditional Chinese or simplified Chinese?

Comment: @Kuttens I write the document in simplified Chinese but I want set the page number in traditional Chinese. Do you mean that if I want set the page numbers in traditional Chinese the whole document should be written in traditional Chinese?

Comment: @Humblerose See the revised answer above.